# WiX localization garbled words under installer properties tab

Tags: localization, wix, installation

I'm trying to do localization in WiX installer. How can I fix the garbled words shown below in the installer properties? The language that I defined is Japanese.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Trying to install your application is part of a developers responsibility, and even more so in the age of WIX than before. WIX is XML code, and also a core tool needed to deliver your application to end users.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong, but the first few questions would be: 1. What Windows version is this? 2. Is the system Japanese? 3. If not, have you installed the Japanese input language or language pack?

Comment: The windows version is 7 and I have installed Japanese language pack in my computer and have tried switch to test the installer. The result still be same and shows the garble words within the installer properties.

Comment: @user1219310 For future reference, a copy/paste of your xml code would be preferable to a screenshot.

Comment: Added a comment to Arnson's answer.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46357578/129130).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't officially support codepage 65001 for UTF-8 -- mostly because of UI problems like this. Try using codepage 932 for ja-JP strings. Also, make sure you're setting the `Package/@SummaryCodepage` attribute (the .wxl file's code page sets `Product/@Codepage`).

Comment: [Cross-linking a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595758/wix-toolset-license-agreement-multi-languages-issue/49605354#49605354) for easy retrieval. I think it relates to the same issue.