# How to make Win64 attribute as a variable in wixlib?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5, wixlib

We have some components in **wixlib** project and different installer projects reference it. The problem is Win64 attribute and several others as per my investigation can be bound only to preprocessor variable.

```
 <Component Id="someid" Guid="someguid" Directory="$(var.FrameworkFolder)" Win64="$(var.Platform64)">
  <File Id="somefile" Name="somename" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.OutputFolder)\somefile"/>
</Component>
```

Currently, that forces us to have the **library dynamically referencing ConfigVariables.wxi from the output project** which is a huge restriction if we won't to have two installers in one solution for example.

May be someone knows a way to make such values injectable after wixlib is already build?

Comment: Not a feature I have used. Still, I am wondering what would happen if you would try a localization variable instead. [They are apparently resolved at link time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452114/129130). I might be having a blond moment, but let's see how that works for you. [I am making use of localization variables here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49605354/129130) for example.

Comment: I am curious if you tried localization variables and if so what the results were?

Comment: Sadly no, I was able to overcome the original issue we have with a quicker way, and now am out of time to try localization variables for that, maybe later, because the root cause is not fixed :)