# How to create a .wxs file which has Chinese named references?

Tags: wix

I have a requirement to refer a file which has a name with Chinese characters. When I try to refer to the file in the product.wxs of my project, I see the below error.

```
A string was provided with characters that are not available in the specified   
database code page 1252.
```

Comment: Essentially you need to set localization settings. Be warned: MSI was not designed for Unicode. Can you avoid Chinese file names? Some more details needed: Are you using localization files? (**`*.wxl`**). What are your settings for `Languages` and `SummaryCodepage` in the `Package` element? What is the `CodePage` set in the `Product` element? Some further hints [in this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49605354/129130). [Sample WiX *.WXL file from github.com](https://github.com/Soldie/adblockplus/blob/05f8b81085d9da9ae03d7e5ddd51ba47c491d01d/installer/src/msi/locale/zh-CN.wxl).

Comment: Yes. we are using .wxl files

Comment: I am not sure what [Code Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) is used for Chinese. Please see [that sample link to github.com](https://github.com/Soldie/adblockplus/blob/05f8b81085d9da9ae03d7e5ddd51ba47c491d01d/installer/src/msi/locale/zh-CN.wxl) (see where it says "*WARNING: Multiple code pages possible*") and test with the appropriate code page set. That link shows possible code pages.