# MSI installer build issue with error 7354 after upgrading InstallShield

Tags: msbuild, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2011

I had Basic MSI installer project in InstallShield 2011. In this project I had multiple languages support. Now I have migrated this installer project to InstallShield 2019. After migrate, this installer project giving below error while building.

> ISDEV : error -7354: The Chinese (Traditional): 中文(繁體) value for string 'IDS_ERROR_68' does not contain a legitimate value for table Error column Message

The installer project was building in InstallShield 2011 but after migrate to InstallShield 2019, it's not able to build.

I'm not able to understand why this happening for some of the strings only and not for all strings of that specific language. Is anyone know the root cause of this issue ? And is there any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Maybe Installshield support can help you? If you don't have a support agreement I would diff the functioning MSI and the new MSI with focus on the Summary Stream. [Here is information on comparing MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546). It probably is just a setting in the property pages centering on language code or similar. I don't have access to Installshield in recent versions.

Comment: Maybe [see this WiX related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49605354/129130) as well. [Codepage Summary property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/codepage-summary). Compare MSI files: `cscript.exe widiffdb.vbs "Setup 1.msi" "Setup 2.msi"` might do the trick?