# Visual Studio Setup Project - desktop shortcut name in none ASCII characters not working ( Russian for ex )

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I cant get to use none ASCII characters ( Russian for ex ) when creating a desktop shortcut name for the "primary output" of the installation.
The text turns to blanks after the installation.
Any ideas?

THANKS!!

Comment: [Just some hints here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595758/wix-toolset-license-agreement-multi-languages-issue) - this relates to WiX though.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul couldn't find much help there, thanks anyways.

Comment: Is the shortcut name correctly in the log file? `msiexec /i your_package.msi /l*vx log.txt`

Comment: @Krishty no its not, characters turn to squares ( unfortunately when i try to copy the squares here it turns to blanks )

Comment: @zachigreenberger If you open the MSI via Orca (or a similar tool) and select the `Shortcut` table, does the name display correctly in the corresponding entry?

Comment: @Krishty the name appears corrupted.. anyways i left this unanswered cause it lost priority for my project.
THANKS EVERYONE FOR YOUR HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to play around with the codepage settings but it seems you might be hitting a design limitation if I am reading correctly the MS docs.

- [Localization of Windows Installer packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/kcx25hzz(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Extracted from the above article:

> The code pages supported for deployment are: 1252 (Neutral, English, French, German, Italian, and Spanish), 936 (Chinese (Simplified)), 950 (Chinese (Traditional)), 932 (Japanese), and 949 (Korean).

Comment: thanks @Bogdan Mitrache for the good reference. though i tried Chinese and Japanese and still the shortcut text turned to blanks. any idea why?

Comment: Maybe you're missing some language packs on your test machine? Have you tried installing other packages that create Russian or Chinese shortcuts?

I don't usually play that much with localized installers, so I might be missing something too.

Comment: Unfortunately the language pack was not the answer